# How to use Union properly

Tags: sql-server, union

This is my first time using UNION and I'm not sure how to fix this to show the correct output that I want. Currently it is showing me 9 outputs, but I want it to show me just 1 (Randy Troy and his gsExperiencePoints) I want it to get the max from one query and to use a where clause from another for only devName 'Blizzard Entertainment'. Thomas Hardy isn't the correct answer as he doesn't play Blizzard games so he is added because he has the most Exp in any game in my database.

[image]

Currently this is my output:

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT
    gamerFirst + ' ' + gamerLast as 'Gamer',
    gsExperiencePoints
FROM GAMER as gr
    INNER JOIN GAME_STAT as gs ON gr.gamerID = gs.gamerID
        INNER JOIN GAME as g ON gs.gameID = g.gameID
            INNER JOIN DEVELOPER as d ON g.devID = d.devID
WHERE gsExperiencePoints = (SELECT MAX(gsExperiencePoints) FROM GAME_STAT)
GROUP BY gsExperiencePoints, gamerFirst, gamerLast
UNION ALL
SELECT
    gamerFirst + ' ' + gamerLast as 'Gamer',
    gsExperiencePoints
FROM GAMER as gr
    INNER JOIN GAME_STAT as gs ON gr.gamerID = gs.gamerID
        INNER JOIN GAME as g ON gs.gameID = g.gameID
            INNER JOIN DEVELOPER as d ON g.devID = d.devID
WHERE devName = 'Blizzard Entertainment'
GROUP BY gsExperiencePoints, gamerFirst, gamerLast;
```

Comment: Some advice here: when you have joins in your SQL statement, **always** qualify all fields with the alias. Everywhere. I don't really want to look at queries like these without knowing what table the columns are selected from. Question: why use GROUP BY on fields without having an aggregate function (like eg SUM)? Did you mean to select distinct values? In that case, `SELECT DISTINCT ...` without the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually need or want a union.  Are you trying to select which 'Blizzard Entertainment' dev has the highest experience points?

Comment: @kicken I'm trying to find which Person who played 'Blizzard Entertainment' games has the highest experience and just show him (Randy Troy)

Comment: @TT. I'm unsure why I put the group by I tend to do that sometimes, but anyways I added the tables in the main post.

Comment: :). In any case, if you don't need to group by, you shouldn't put them in your query. For more complex and involved queries over a lot of data, that may impact performance considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one does the selection of the entire list.

The UNION adds the second one to the first one.

You probably want the INTERSECT operation instead of UNION. This would require that the records in the first selection have some criterion from the second selection.  The UNION operator simply appends the records from the second operation to the records from the first operation.

These operations are documented at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191523(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: I briefly toyed with INTERSECT and it gave me nothing at all this time, any other hints?

Comment: Perhaps you should try adding the where clause from the second selection to the where clause from the first and get rid of the UNION and the second clause all together.  The WHERE clause would then be WHERE gsExperiencePoints = (SELECT MAX(gsExperiencePoints) FROM GAME_STAT) AND devName = 'Blizzard Entertainment'

Comment: I tried that but it also gives me nothing I was told to think of the question as two and put them together.

Comment: Actually, since you really want the game stats it should probably be the lead table with the other information from the other tables joined to it and the WHERE clause adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See if this does it:

```
SELECT
    gr.gamerFirst + ' ' + gr.gamerLast as Gamer,
    gs.gsExperiencePoints
FROM
    gamer AS gr
    INNER JOIN game_stat AS gs ON 
        gs.gamerid=g.gamerid
WHERE
    gs.gsexperiencepoints=(
        SELECT
            MAX(gs.gsexperiencepoints)
        FROM
            game_stat AS gs
            INNER JOIN game AS g ON 
                 g.gameid=gs.gameid
            INNER JOIN developer AS dev ON 
                 dev.devid=g.devid
        WHERE
            dev.devname='Blizzard Entertainment'
    );
```

In words: select all gamers that have experience points equal to the maximum experience points for games made by Blizzard Entertainment.

---

PS: I don't like all-caps for table or column names, or any other database object for that matter.

Comment: Heh, I edited my answer several times, I think I about got what you want. If you have any questions in the future, it is better to include a table layout and sample data so it's easier to fiddle around with it. See this article: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/).

Answer (score 0):

This query should give the user who has the highest experience points and played a blizzard game.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    gr.gamerFirst + ' ' + gr.gamerLast as Gamer,
    maxGs.gsExperiencePoints
FROM GAMER as gr
INNER JOIN GAME_STAT as gs ON gr.gamerID = gs.gamerID
INNER JOIN GAME as g ON gs.gameID = g.gameID
INNER JOIN DEVELOPER d ON d.devID=g.devID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT gs.gamerID, MAX(gs.gsExperiencePoints) as gsExperiencePoints
    FROM GAME_STAT gs 
    GROUP BY gs.gamerID
) maxGs ON maxGS.gamerID = gr.gamerID
WHERE 
    d.devName='Blizzard Entertainment'
ORDER BY
    maxGs.gsExperiencePoints DESC
```

The inner sub query first selects a list of all gamers and their maximum experience points across all games.  This is then joined up with the outer query which selects a list of gamers who have a 'Blizzard Entertainment' game. The end result is a list of each blizzard player along with their maximum experience points.  Lastly it just puts them in descending order and takes the first record.